# Cython: python int to uint8_t

Tags: python, c++, type-conversion, cython, typeerror

For my work, I need to use this C++ function with python.

```
std::vector<std::string> pinCertificate(const std::vector<uint8_t>& certificate, bool local)
```

I've already translated the prototype to this in Cython

```
vector[string] pinCertificate(const vector[uint8_t]& certificate, const boolean& local)
```

But the real problem comes when I try to use it. I always get the following error, or a segfault.

```
TypeError: an integer is required
```

Here's how I call my function:

```
# cert_id is a simple string
certificate = [np.uint8(x) for x in list(cert_id.encode())]

result = self.dring.config.pin_certificate(certificate, local)
```

I don't know why it is crashing, certificate contains only `numpy.uint8`'s.

Is there anything that I did wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Well, it seems that the problem came from the internal C++ code I had.